# How to access the wamp localhost in android device for testing?

Tags: android

In emulator am use this 10.0.2.2 ip address to test the application it work fine,but it not work for testing in android device.am connect the device through USB cable.How to test the app in device with local host.Can anyone know help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use The WIFI That is The Best Solution of your Problem..And Use Your IP Address for Connection ...from android device to the local server..:-)

Comment: but i run through my pc.am not have WIFI dongle.

Comment: bro then you will have to take your server domain then only you can send the Request that server through your android device

Answer (score 2):

1. Start Wamp server on pc
2. Click Wamp windows taskbar
3. Click "Put Online" (bottom of wamp)
4. Run command prompt
5. type ipconfig and enter
6. Note your IPv4 address (192.168.1.206 in my case)
7. Make sure your pc and android connect with same wifi
8. Make sure your wifi network as "Home Network"
9. Open browser on android
10. Type your IPv4 address

I hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

USB won't provide network to you.

Hope this will help you.

[How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: Actually, USB can provide networking, in two cases.  One is that ADB port forwards (under an SDK installation) will allow the PC to open a connection to the device, but not the other way around, unless you use one connection as a tunnel for others.  The second is that most tethering solutions end up establishing a bidirectionally connectable network between the PC and device, though there are many potential concerns in having tethering enabled.

Answer (score 1):

use Connectify Software, and insert the IP address of the system, in your android code instead of 10.0.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 Users

> 1. go to Control Panel-> System and Security->Windows Defender Firewall->Turn Windows Defender Firewall on or off.

Set both private and public network settings to off.

> 2. open a command prompt. type ipconfig and note your IP.
> 3. on your android device open a browser and type in your pc's IP.

I used this with WIFI and it worked fine.